# Django - how to redirect to index page upon logout?

Tags: python, django, authentication

I'm trying to implement a simple page redirect to the index page if user authentication fails.

Imagine that I have two paths:

```
www.xyz.com/app/
www.xyz.com/app/user
```

The first renders the index page, and the second is the authorized user landing page on successful login.

In my `views.py` file, I have

```
def index(request):
  return render(request, "app/index.html")

def userLogin(request):
  loginUser = authenticate(username = request.POST["username"], password = request.POST["password"])

  if loginUser is not None:
    if not loginUser.is_active:
      loginUser.is_active = True
      loginUser.save()

      login(request, loginUser)
      return HttpResponse(reverse(user))    
    else:
      return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps({"login" : "failed"}))

def userLogout(request):
  logout(request)
  return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(index))
```

and `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = patterns("",
  url(r'^$', views.index, name = "index"),
  url(r'^user/$', views.user, name = "user"),
  url(r'^registerNewUser/$', views.registerNewUser),
  url(r'^userLogin/$', views.userLogin),
  url(r'^user/userLogout/$', views.userLogout),
)
```

The logout function is accessed via an Ajax POST request, and in the logs, I see

```
 [11/Jul/2013 09:08:00] "POST /app/user/userLogout/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
 [11/Jul/2013 09:08:00] "GET /app/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5039
```

but the index page is not loading.  However, if I refresh the page, the index page loads, due a conditional call to `request.user.is_authenticated()` which triggers the same `HttpResponseRedirect` call and parameters on fail.

Comment: What does your [`LOGOUT_URL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#logout-url) setting look like ?

Comment: `LOGOUT_URL = "/app/"` is what I put in my settings file.  It doesn't work, neither does "/app/index.html`

Comment: How about this: `(r'^user/userLogout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout',
                          {'next_page': '/app/'})` ?

Comment: If you're making an ajax request to logout, won't you need to use Javascript to perform the redirect?

Comment: @ChrisMcKinnel, that's what I ended up doing, but my original hope was to have the Django server execute the redirect without any JS response handling required.

Comment: @karthikr, thanks for the suggestion, but it didn't work.  I ended up passing a JSON success object back to the page and executing the redirect via manually setting `document.location.href`.

Comment: Yeah I don't think you can do that 'cause the ajax call would just get  the redirected page as a response and you'd still have to do something with it, no?

Comment: @Jason That's right, the ajax way won't let Django handle the redirect unfortunately. However I wouldn't log in with ajax in the first place nor would I logout. Why are you using ajax for it?

Answer (score 0):

```
If login fail i mean in else case return render(request, "app/index.html") instead
of return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps({"login" : "failed"}))

**updated userLogin**

def userLogin(request):
    loginUser = authenticate(username = request.POST["username"],
    password = request.POST["password"])

if loginUser is not None:
if not loginUser.is_active:
  loginUser.is_active = True
  loginUser.save()

  login(request, loginUser)
  return HttpResponse(reverse(user))    
else:
  return render(request, "app/index.html")
```